# How to select nth child of element using Xpath with Selenium WebDriver. JAVA

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have the following `HTML` code:

```
<div class="t2-selector">  
    <div>  
        <div class="inactive">USA</div>  
        <div class="inactive">Google</div>  
        <div class="inactive">Microsoft</div>  
        <div class="inactive">Apple</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="">Europe</div>
        <div class="selected">BT</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="">Indices</div>
        <div>Vodafone</div>
        <div>Renault</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="">Currencies</div>
        <div>EUR/USD</div>
        <div>GBP/USD</div>
        <div>USD/JPY</div>
        <div>USD/CHF</div>
        <div>AUD/USD</div>
        <div>USD/CAD</div>
   </div>
```

I can select a group by Xpath `xpath = "//div[contains(text(),'Currencies')]"`
What I need is to select a child in `Currencies` list by it's number.
I need something like CSS `div:nth-child(2)` but I can't use CSS here since CSS doesn't really support selecting an element by text.
So is there `nth-child` analog for Xpath?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are not using classes? And what are you planning to do with the selected element? Assuming you want to do styling [as you added the css tag] and didn't just add the empty class tag for fun couldn't [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/ufwxbhs9/) be a more simple solution?

Comment: Do you know Selenium WebDriver what is?

Comment: I do not, i just realize i didn't even really look at the tags, i am sorry! I guess this technology requiers xpath selectors, not css ones. You simply added the `css` tag for reference to the `nth-child` selector then i assume?

Comment: Selenium WebDriver is used for automation web testings. In the code above you can see no classes, they used for inactive indication only. So I need the `Xpath` or `CSS` expression to select the desired element and click on it, maybe extract it's attribute, never changing it. And as about the `CSS` tag I used - you are right, it is because I was looking for `nth-child` analog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
//div[contains(text(),'Currencies')]/following-sibling::div[1]
```

Please note that the index starts from 1 not 0.

Check the following link : http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp

Answer (score 0):

Using **descendant**  -

```
//div[contains(text(),'Currencies')]/descendant::div[2]
```